# Using the sort -k to format a text file

Tags: bash, sh

I am stuck using the sort command to output `students.txt` into 4 separate columns. I have tried going the route of `sort -k 4n` but it still does not work.

I want to be able to output the `students.txt` into 4 columns of data under the headings of the first `awk` statement:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "%-12s %-9s %-12s %-12s\n", "Family Name", "initials", 
"Interviewer Initials", "Interview Time"}'
awk '{printf "%-12s %-9s %-12s %-12s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4}' | students.txt | sort - 
k3.4
```

Comment: This question needs improvement.  You don't give an example of `students.txt`, nor have you explained what formatting you mean to achieve from `sort`.  Do you want it in some particular order?

Comment: Sort, doesn't work well with multiple separator, i.e. several spaces can't be considered a separator.

Comment: Welcome to SO,  add samples for input and output with code tags in your post too.

Comment: Please read the [help] and [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give sort the separtor. In your case the comma sign.
Here is how to sort the 3 column of a comma separated input.

```
~ $ cat example.txt 
foo,bar,baz
aoo,bug,bug
foo,zzz,boo

$ sort -t, -k 3 example.txt 
foo,bar,baz
foo,zzz,boo
aoo,bug,bug
```

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a file called students.txt that sounds like what you are dealing with.  I added the results of the interview to give another column:

```
Smith   A RCB 09:00  Good
Smith   A TEA 12:00  Bad
Jones   B DEF 12:00  Bad
Aaron   A BZD 12:00  Ugly
Roberts C RCB 12:00  Good
Smith   A JRR 10:30  Good
Aaron   R RCB 10:30  Bad
```

This script should be enough to give you the idea of what is required for the sort:

```
sort  -k4,4 -k1,2 students.txt |
awk  'BEGIN {printf "%-12s %-9s %-20s %-20s\n", "Family Name", "Initials", "Interviewer Initials", "Interview Time"}
{printf "%-12s %-9s %-20s %-20s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

This results in:

```
Family Name  Initials  Interviewer Initials Interview Time
Smith        A         RCB                  09:00
Aaron        R         RCB                  10:30
Smith        A         JRR                  10:30
Aaron        A         BZD                  12:00
Jones        B         DEF                  12:00
Roberts      C         RCB                  12:00
Smith        A         TEA                  12:00
```

1. The `sort` is using the spaces to decide which fields to sort on.  Notice, I am sorting on column 4 followed by columns 1 and 2.  If you left out the ,4 after the 4, the sort would sort all the way to the end of record so the Ugly interview would come up last inside the 12:00 records.
2. You only need to run `awk` once, the BEGIN block runs on startup to print the headers.
3. The next `awk` block prints out the four columns of interest using the format specified.